# Replacing empty values in a CSV using powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am faced with a challenge and I am new to development (but a long time sys admin).

Basically I have a CSV (well many CSV's but I want to start with 1) that contains some empty fields.

I was hoping I could use powershell to load the csv in, then do a find and replace, then output the file using the following code.... But I can't specify a zero length string. (For obvious reasons, you can't search for nothing I suppose)...

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [io.file]::readalltext("C:\BainesWingData.CSV").replace("","TEST") | Out-File c:\result.
csv -Encoding ascii -Force
```

All I want to do is replace the empty fields with "0". Here is an example of the CSV. The location of the blank fields can vary.

```
Timestamp,Baines Wing - 0006.B0006 0006 EM03 (kWh),Baines Wing - 0006.B0006 0006 EM04 (kWh),Baines Wing - 0006.B0006 0006 EM05 (kWh),Baines Wing - 0006.B0016 0006 EM01 (kWh)
31/01/2014 20:00,,,,
31/01/2014 20:30,6,8,6,19
31/01/2014 21:00,5,9,6,19
31/01/2014 21:30,5,8,6,20
31/01/2014 22:00,5,8,6,19
31/01/2014 22:30,6,8,5,20
31/01/2014 23:00,5,7,6,19
31/01/2014 23:30,5,8,6,20
01/02/2014 00:00,5,8,5,19
01/02/2014 00:30,5,8,6,20
01/02/2014 01:00,5,8,6,19
01/02/2014 19:00,5,7,7,19
01/02/2014 19:30,,,,20
01/02/2014 20:00,,,,
```

As you can see, there are some empty fields for some of the rows. This breaks the application which these CSV files must be read into, so my goal is to come up witha  script which runs on these CSV's to replace the empty fields with just a 0.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Regards
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not very elegant but this should work :

```
$csv=Import-Csv .\csv.csv -Header "time","EM03","EM02","EM05", "EM01"  
$csv | %{
    if($_.EM03 -eq "") {$_.EM03="0"}
    if($_.EM02 -eq "") {$_.EM02="0"}
    if($_.EM05 -eq "") {$_.EM05="0"}
    if($_.EM01 -eq "") {$_.EM01="0"}
} 
$csv|export-csv .\new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi there! That seems to work however it wraps everything in "" quotes on the output CSV and also appears to insert two blank rows at the end of the file """,,,,
"",,,," any ideas?

Comment: the double quotes are generated by export-csv, if you dont want these create your own export function. I guess you have empty line in you source file that's why you've got blank lines

Comment: Ah yes I see now, oh well thanks for the starting point :-) I will see what I can muster up now I know its feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing ,, with ,0, instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

The ",,," in the CSV are the empty fields I am trying to fill with "0"

Comment: A CSV file is just a text file. ,, is not an empty field, it just represents one, so you replace each instance of ,, with ,0, therebye filling your 'empty' fields with a zero.